# SSIS Script Task Reflection reference permissions

Tags: c#, dll, ssis, package, sql-agent-job

I have built software that is capable of exporting DTSX package automatically. This package among other objects has also a ScriptTask (C#). All are compiled and run just fine.

Now the new requirement is to call a class in that ScriptTask, which exists inside an external DLL we have built, so other applications can consume the same code. So we implemented a loading mechanism of the DLL, using reflection.

```
Assembly clientLib = Assembly.LoadFrom("C:\\......\\mylibrary.dll");
Type licenseCheckType = clientLib.GetType("myclass");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(licenseCheckType);
```

The code is running just fine, but there are several permission issues during deployment.

1. Running the package from DataTools, the package fails because cannot find the file. If I executed the DataTools as administrator is working. Still, I don't get it, as a user I should be able to browse the file.
2. Running the package from SQLAgent(this is important), the package fails. If I set the SQL Agent service user with "Local System" or "Administrator" user the is working.

I am looking for a way to find how I can make it work with a simple user by adding permissions to that path if necessary, but still, keep failing. I tried to set a simple domain user as SQLAgent Service account and give Full Control as a start to the directory without success.

```
Error: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Implementing the loading mechanism from GAC, is working, but I would like to explore the other way as the DLL in my case, this DLL is referencing a LiteDb file in the system directory, and it would be nice to have them all together.

```
Assembly clientLib = Assembly.Loadm("mylibrary");
Type licenseCheckType = clientLib.GetType("myclass");
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(licenseCheckType);
```

**As a summary:**

Using the GAC

1. UI will reference the local DLL because exist in bin folder
2. SSIS will reference the GAC DLL because of loading from GAC, which references a db file from local folder

Using the Local (problematic)

1. UI will reference the local DLL because exist in bin folder
2. SSIS will reference the local DLL because of loading from local folder, which references a db file from local folder

Comment: Why do you load your assembly from the File System - it is prone to errors and access problems, like you reported. You can load assembly from GAC - `Assembly.Load("SampleAssembly, Version=1.0.2004.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8744b20f8da049e3")` - necessary to provide publickeytoken.

Comment: The assembly is referencing another assembly which references LiteDB which cannot be part of GAC.

Comment: I can only suggest using SysInternals [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to monitor access to your DLLs when receiving access errors. It could reveal which permissions are still missing.

Comment: Of course a solution we provided is to make the LiteDb dll to use a path for accessing the actual fb file in the disk. But any how it would be good to know why loading from disk is so prone to errors.